# Why isnt it finding the element's innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function getViews(){
    $.get (
    "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=16",
        function parse(data) {
            var userviews = $(data).find("#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserStatisticsPane_lProfileViewsStatistics").html();
            alert(userviews);
        }
    );
}

getViews();
```

I basically want it to do the same thing as the line below, except there's more to my jquery function that I didnt give because I know that works:

```
alert(document.getElementById('ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserStatisticsPane_lProfileViewsStatistics').innerHTML)
```

Comment: What's `data`'s value?

Comment: For me its working i get an alert with "3,781,482". Do you call it from outside the website and get access denied?

Comment: @SG86, it alerts `null`

Comment: Nope not for me, i tryed it directly on the page via console

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it in console and it works fine. It may be something else in my function.

Comment: @Alex Have you eliminated the possibility of same-origin restrictions? You haven't made that explicit in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give details but I suspect your `success` callback is not even executing (i.e., the `alert()` is not firing) because the AJAX request is failing. Your code will possibly not work unless it's hosted at `http://www.roblox.com`.
I can see the following error in the browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=16`.
>   Origin `http://test.local` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

*In Firebug, Chrome and recent IE you can open the console with <kbd>F12</kbd>. In Firefox you can use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+K</kbd>.*